# Cordova iOS Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP

Tags: ios, cordova, whitelist

I'm building an iOS app and recently upgraded cordova-ios to 4.1.0 and started using: cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.

The problem is that now I get the error message `Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP` while trying to load dependencies, so the app won't start.

It's trying to load systemjs dependencies over file://, but I included  in my config.js.

I have no clue how to fix this. Does anyone have experience with this bevaviour?

cordova version: 6.1,0
cordova ios version: 4.1.0

related config.xml bit:

```
<access origin="*" />
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

Comment: It's a known limitation of the WKWebView, you can try to install the `wkwebview-engine-localhost`plugin that adds a webserver and should fix your issue https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/wkwebview-engine-localhost

Comment: Did you have any success with this?

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Any idea if Apple will still accept your app to the store using this solution?

Answer (score 15):

Install this one plugin (cordova-ios 6+)

```
  cordova plugin add https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr
```

then set

```
  <preference name="AllowUntrustedCerts"  value="true" />
  <preference name="InterceptRemoteRequests" value="all" />
  <preference name="allowFileAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
  <preference name="allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
```

Comment: You save my day,
Just note that some times the preference are add automatically.

Comment: tried all other methods, only this one work!

Comment: `kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1` after trying this

Comment: This plugin has now been superseded by https://github.com/oracle/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr

Answer (score 13):

For Cordova iOS 6+ just need to install the following plugin.

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/AraHovakimyan/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix
```

This plugin does not depend on any other additional plugins and does not require additional permissions.

Comment: You saved me big time!

Comment: this plugin breaks the build on the latest version of cordova-ios

Comment: Hi  João Pimentel Ferreira,
Please let me know the details of the problem and what Cordova-ios version are you using?

Comment: No need for plugins, just use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74955518/767865

Answer (score 12):

Install the following plugins:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine    
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr    
cordova plugin add https://github.com/TheMattRay/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix
```

Add to `config.xml`:

```
<platform name="ios">
  ...
   <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true"/>
  ...
 </platform>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you work with cordova-ios ^6.0.0. you need only to modify your `config.xml` file:

```
<platform name="ios">
  ...
   <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
   <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" /> 
  ...
</platform>
```

No need to install any additional plugins.

See [Cordova iOS 6.0.0 Released](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/01/cordova-ios-release-6.0.0.html) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with my cordova project (actually Ionic v1) and I fix it with the following command:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins.git#wkwebview-engine-localhost
```

This will install a webserver that runs locally and the error should be gone after that. After you run that command, just run:

```
cordova prepare ios
```

or remove all plugins and reinstall:

```
rm -rf plugins/
cordova platform add ios
```

Make sure you have this in your config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my ionic v1 Cordova project. For me the solution was to migrate to capacitor, like this:

- Start a New Ionic v1 project (% ionic start Bienchen blank --type ionic1)
- Answer "yes" when the cli asked if to integrate "capacitor".
- Checkout my Sources to the www-folder of the new Ionic v1 project
- Build the project with capacitor (% ionic capacitor build iOS)

Keep in mind the the Cordova config.xml than is not longer used, instead configure in Xcode Project.