# Cordova (PhoneGap): How to see errors or console.log when running cordova run ios

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phaser-framework

I am running a cordova app with the Phaser Game Engine...

I am supposed to be displaying an image on the screen but for some reason the image is not appearing.  Instead there is a placeholder for it.
I am guessing that cordova would most likely have a error about it but I can't access it when I'm running ios: `cordova run ios`

When I run it on the browser everything is working properly: `cordova run browser`

Comment: Open Safari => Develop ([enable](https://osxdaily.com/2011/11/03/enable-the-develop-menu-in-safari/)) => select your device ([enable debug on device](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-debug-on-iphone)) and click on index.html. You can reload your app to see initial error messages

Comment: console.log does show up there as u have instructed...but no errors there to see why no image is appearing in the ios version eventhough it works in the browser version of cordova

Comment: Maybe check the network tab. Probably wrong path to the image or something is not copied properly

Comment: I just checked the network tab....only the placeholder images are there...the actual images that I want are not there...don't know why....I'm using cordova....is there a extra step I need to take to use images properly in the iOS version of a cordova app???

Comment: do i need to use url()??

Comment: No you don't need but things have changed a bit since the switch to wkvebview. It's hard to answer whitout knowing what exactly you're doing. Are you loading a file or just some images in your www folder?

Comment: i'm loading images inside www folder..for example www/assets/sprites/emptytile.png and www/img/logo.png my code works on the browser but on ios these images don't display....

Comment: Every time I run the ios project...it automatically closes off the Safari browser...after I open the browser to go to the console.log of the App...it only shows the logs that happen after opening and not prior...is there anyway to see everything??

Comment: Yes there is a reload button on the top left. With this button you can reload the application without detaching the debugger. Or `command + R`

Comment: Correct...I can now see the errors: Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.   AND ANOTHER ERROR: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/bliss/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FC94FDB4-35CA-4AF6-B2B0-E6E5E93B75AE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6AAB91F2-E193-484D-B79D-A85C4E71B572/HelloCordova.app/www/assets/sprites/emptytile.png due to access control checks.   Any idea how to fix?  thanks

Comment: Solved with this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451720/cordova-ios-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http

Comment: You actually don't need a plugin for this to work [read here](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/01/cordova-ios-release-6.0.0.html). The part about `<preference name="scheme" value="app" />` and `<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />`

Comment: Ok...I followed instructions and it did work...thank you for helping and sharing knowledge...

Comment: hi the above worked for ios simulator....but what about debugging on android emulator? How to see the console.logs then?

Comment: Enable debug tools enable debugging and connect with your chrome browser from this url chrome://inspect/#devices

Answer (score 1):

Hi If you somehow not figured out what is the issue then here is a tip.
Try using relative paths for images because absolute paths work in browser but not in android.
and regarding the log issue, I am looking for the same thing.
Wish me luck