# Phaser 3 in Cordova App: How to use images properly in a iOS version

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap, phaser-framework

I am using Phaser 3 inside a Cordova App.
I am trying to display an image on the screen.
The code works properly in the browser version.
Therefore if I run: `cordova run browser`
then everything displays properly.

But if I run `cordova run ios`

then the images do not appear properly.
I have opened the app using Xcode too and I don't see any relevant errors to it.

Here is the relevant section:

```
function preload ()
{
    console.log('preload.......')
    this.load.image("emptytile", "./assets/sprites/emptytile.png");
    // this.load.image("logo", "url(../img/logo.png)");
    this.load.image("logo", "./assets/sprites/logo.png");
}

function create ()
{


    this.add.image(200, 200, "emptytile");   
    this.add.image(30, 100, "logo"); 
    
    const ThirtyConsonantsButton = this.add.text(100, 100, 'Thirty Consonants', { fill: '#0f0' })
    ThirtyConsonantsButton.setInteractive();

    ThirtyConsonantsButton.on('pointerdown', () => { console.log('pointerdown'); });

  
}
```

And then in order to see any possible errors I open the app thru Xcode and the console debug area shows the following:

```
2021-03-25 19:25:01.049522+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] Apache Cordova native platform version 6.2.0 is starting.
2021-03-25 19:25:01.049690+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2021-03-25 19:25:01.058846+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] Could not load the "LaunchStoryboard" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "io.cordova.hellocordova"
2021-03-25 19:25:01.291165+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] The preference key "AllowNewWindows" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2021-03-25 19:25:01.292422+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] The preference key "MediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2021-03-25 19:25:01.297305+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] The preference key "AllowBackForwardNavigationGestures" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2021-03-25 19:25:01.297452+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] The preference key "Allow3DTouchLinkPreview" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2021-03-25 19:25:01.297533+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] CDVWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2021-03-25 19:25:01.297660+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] Using WKWebView
2021-03-25 19:25:01.298095+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] [CDVTimer][console] 0.048995ms
2021-03-25 19:25:01.298296+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.058055ms
2021-03-25 19:25:01.299815+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.384974ms
2021-03-25 19:25:01.300050+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.066042ms
2021-03-25 19:25:01.300178+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 2.219081ms
2021-03-25 19:25:01.442929+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process HelloCordova
2021-03-25 19:25:01.443112+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2021-03-25 19:25:01.443229+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2021-03-25 19:25:02.073818+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] The preference key "AutoHideSplashScreen" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2021-03-25 19:25:02.884798+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] Running cordova-ios@6.2.0
2021-03-25 19:25:02.885008+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947]      Phaser v3.53.1 (WebGL | Web Audio)  https://phaser.io
2021-03-25 19:25:02.885198+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] resizeGame
2021-03-25 19:25:02.970339+0800 HelloCordova[23044:1549947] preload.......
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Cordova and Cordova-ios in following versions:

> cordova v. 11.0.0.
>
> cordova-ios v. 6.0.0.

Then you can edit your config.xml file in following way:

```
<platform name="ios">
    // ... some different config elements for ios
    <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
    <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" /> 
</platform>
```

Your images then will be loaded without need for additional cordova plugins.

Answer (score 1):

This post had the answer:

[Cordova iOS Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451720/cordova-ios-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http)

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/AraHovakimyan/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix
```

Hope this helps other people in the future....

Comment: No need for plugins, just use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74955518/767865